# Calculate weighted average life in R

Tags: r, data.table, weighted-average

I would like to calculate the weighted average life (*WAL*) of a loan over time in R. The formula to calculate the *WAL* is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted-average_life).

I have the following sample data created in R.

**Sample data**

```
library(data.table)
DT<-data.table(date=c(rep(seq(from = 2015, to = 2016.25,by = .25),2),
seq(from = 2015, to = 2017.5,by = .5)),
           value=c(rep(100,5), 0, 100, 80, 60, 40, 20, 0, 100, 70, 40, 30, 20, 0),
           id=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=6))

DT

       date value id
 1: 2015.00   100  a
 2: 2015.25   100  a
 3: 2015.50   100  a
 4: 2015.75   100  a
 5: 2016.00   100  a
 6: 2016.25     0  a
 7: 2015.00   100  b
 8: 2015.25    80  b
 9: 2015.50    60  b
 10: 2015.75    40  b
 11: 2016.00    20  b
 12: 2016.25     0  b
 13: 2015.00   100  c
 14: 2015.50    70  c
 15: 2016.00    40  c
 16: 2016.50    30  c
 17: 2017.00    20  c
 18: 2017.50     0  c
```

Thus every loan in this example has a maturity of 5 years and at maturity date the loan is completely amortized. Note: The dates are not always incremented by one semi year or one quarter, but are may differ (see sample data).

To calculate the the *WAL* I have created the **following R code**

```
Counter <- unique(DT$id)

# LOOP OVER ID
for (i in 1:length(Counter)) {

# SUBSET ONE ID
DTSub <- DT[id == Counter[i], ]

# LOOP OVER THE AMORTIZATIONDATES
CounterSub <- unique(DTSub$date)

for (j in 1:length(CounterSub)) {

# SUBSET RANGE OF DATES IN COUNTERSUB
DTSub_Date <- DTSub[date >= CounterSub[j], ]
DTSub_Date[, t := abs(min(date)-date)]
DT[id == Counter[i] & date == CounterSub[j], 
       wal_calc := round(sum(abs(diff(DTSub_Date$value)) 
       / max(DTSub_Date$value) * DTSub_Date$t[2:nrow(DTSub_Date)]),3)]

}
}
```

**The output of the code**

```
DT

       date value id wal_calc
 1: 2015.00   100  a    1.250
 2: 2015.25   100  a    1.000
 3: 2015.50   100  a    0.750
 4: 2015.75   100  a    0.500
 5: 2016.00   100  a    0.250
 6: 2016.25     0  a    0.000
 7: 2015.00   100  b    0.750
 8: 2015.25    80  b    0.625
 9: 2015.50    60  b    0.500
 10: 2015.75    40  b    0.375
 11: 2016.00    20  b    0.250
 12: 2016.25     0  b    0.000
 13: 2015.00   100  c    1.300
 14: 2015.50    70  c    1.143
 15: 2016.00    40  c    1.125
 16: 2016.50    30  c    0.833
 17: 2017.00    20  c    0.500
 18: 2017.50     0  c    0.000
```

The output of the code is correct (`wal_calc`) but uses a double `for` loop, and hence is slow on relatively large datasets (mine has 77k rows and 200 columns).

The first `for` loop subsets the IDs and the second subsets future dates (by id, based on the first subset).

**Request**

I would like to be able to generate *WALS*  on this sample data in way faster and more efficient manner and avoid this double for loop. There might be a very simple solution to this problem.

If anything is unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it without `for` loops.

```
DT[order(date), WAL := {
  pmts <- matrix(value[-.N] - value[-1L], 
                 nrow = n2 <- .N - 1L, ncol = n2)
  ts <- matrix(date[-1L] - date[-.N], nrow = n2, ncol = n2)
  ts[upper.tri(ts)] <- 0
  ts <- apply(ts, 2, cumsum)
  c(colSums(pmts * ts) / value[-.N], 0)}, by = id]
DT
     date value id       WAL
# 1: 2015.00   100  a 1.2500000
# 2: 2015.25   100  a 1.0000000
# 3: 2015.50   100  a 0.7500000
# 4: 2015.75   100  a 0.5000000
# 5: 2016.00   100  a 0.2500000
# 6: 2016.25     0  a 0.0000000
# 7: 2015.00   100  b 0.7500000
# 8: 2015.25    80  b 0.6250000
# 9: 2015.50    60  b 0.5000000
# 10: 2015.75    40  b 0.3750000
# 11: 2016.00    20  b 0.2500000
# 12: 2016.25     0  b 0.0000000
# 13: 2015.00   100  c 1.3000000
# 14: 2015.50    70  c 1.1428571
# 15: 2016.00    40  c 1.1250000
# 16: 2016.50    30  c 0.8333333
# 17: 2017.00    20  c 0.5000000
# 18: 2017.50     0  c 0.0000000
```

Comment: I just wanted to make the same comment. No it does not btw. For the rest your answer seems to work. Also, it is way faster!

Comment: @DavevanBrecht OK. It would help to have that in your example.

Comment: Ok, I'll change the sample data

Comment: @DavevanBrecht fixed. I hate using `apply`, but it seems the fastest way. Also realized we don't need `sweep`, usage of which always confuses me

Comment: Great thanks for your kind help. Your answer seems to reproduce my previous code but in a more efficient way.

Comment: linear algebra is at the heart of all for loop avoidance ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you could use `apply` instead for the first subset. Then you would just need on for loop.

```
ids <- unique(DT$id)

DTSub <- apply(DT, 1, function(x) if x$id %in% ids)

CounterSub <- unique(DTSub$date)
```

Comment: Thanks Seekheart. However, ideally I would like to have a fast data.table solution, since the function is used in a Shiny application and should be able to calculate the WALS on the fly (i.e. as fast and efficient as possible). There must be other ways of doing this. I already searched for some specific packages but could not find them.